# Return on assets for companies affected by same events

Tags: accounting

I am new to accounting and was looking at the Return on Assets. I have two questions on this notion. First one is a bit silly :  if company X's ROA is 5%, it means that every dollar that X invested in assets generated 5 cents of net income. But aren't they losing money here, or does it mean they generated 1.05$ ?

I was also looking at the ROA for companies affected by the same events. Nike's ROA for 2020, Covid year, is 16.58% meanwhile Under Armour's one is -11.12% even if they are in the same industry. It is clear that large firms could resist better to Covid but how is the difference so big ? The numbers don't even have the same sign.